# correction for query w

Tags: mysql, sql-server

While executing the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (u.name),u.class,
(SELECT ( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE subject LIKE 'biology' AND u.id=m.id) AS biology,
(SELECT ( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE subject LIKE 'chemistry' AND u.id=m.id) AS chemistry,
(SELECT ( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE subject LIKE ' physics' AND u.id=m.id) AS physics,
(SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE u.id=m.id) AS TOTAL,
(SELECT SUM(outof) FROM marklist WHERE u.id=m.id) AS OUTOF,


((SELECT SUM( markscored) FROM marklist WHERE u.id=m.id)/(SELECT SUM(outof) FROM marklist WHERE u.id=m.id)*100) as percentage
FROM  u, marklist m
WHERE u.id=m.userid
```

I'm getting an error as:

> ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row

How can I solve this?

Comment: The subquery returns more than one row, and that subquery needs to return a single scalar value for it to make sense.  Please take a few moments and format your question, just as you expect the SO community to take time to answer it.

Comment: pls correct my query to get a exact output of :+---------+-------+-------+--------+-------+-----------+-----------+
|name  |class |biology| chemistry|physics| total | outof|percentage|
+--------+-------+-------+---------+-------+--------+---------------+
|arun    | 5  |  45  |  42  |  40 |  150  | 127  |84.6|

Comment: Please include sample data and expected output. It is not so nice to just dump a query on SO with no explanation.

Comment: what explanation you require pls reply..........

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function

Comment: if i avoid DISCTINCT i will get a repeated output of the same student.......

Comment: i get my output by using this query

Comment: SELECT  u.name,u.class,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'biology' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS biology,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'chemistry' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS chemistry,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'physics' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS physics,
SUM( markscored) AS TOTAL,
SUM(outof) AS OUTOF
FROM  u, marklist m
WHERE u.id=m.userid
GROUP BY u.name,u.class;

Answer (score 0):

May following is helpful for you.
The divisor can not be 0, so use NULLIF change it to NULL.

```
    SELECT  u.name,u.class,
       SUM( markscored) AS TOTAL,
       SUM(outof) AS OUTOF
       SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'biology' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS biology,
       SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'chemistry' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS chemistry,
       SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'physics' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS physics,
       SUM( markscored)/NULLIF(SUM(outof),0) as percentage

    FROM  u, marklist m
    WHERE u.id=m.userid
    GROUP BY u.name,u.class
```

Comment: SELECT  u.name,u.class,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'biology' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS biology,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'chemistry' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS chemistry,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'physics' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS physics,
SUM( markscored) AS TOTAL,
SUM(outof) AS OUTOF
FROM  u, marklist m
WHERE u.id=m.userid
GROUP BY u.name,u.class;